# EPROTO when trying to sock.end in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, https, server, localhost

I am trying to create a simple node server and call it. Here is what I am doing:

```
var net = require('net');
const https = require('https');

var srv = net.createServer(function(sock) {
  sock.end('Hello world\n');
});
srv.listen(0, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + srv.address().port);
  https.get('https://localhost:' + srv.address().port);
});
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Listening on port 35147
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPROTO 140575534664576:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:

    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:833:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:382:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:603:3)
    at TLSSocket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:835:10)
```

I am trying to run that code here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php.

How could I make the `sock.end` or is there an easier way to create a node server listener? I.e. without using the sockets.

Comment: is it an HTTP or HTTPS server?

Comment: @user253751, i dont know

Comment: why don't you know?